# How to dynamically checkout feature branches from multiple repositories via Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

first and foremost: there are multiple similar questions already answered on here, but none of them could really help me with my problem.

I think I need some help creating an advanced CI pipeline. The project I'm working on is splitted into multiple repositories and each one manages a particular aspect (web app, common methods, etc). I'm currently creating a CI workflow for managing integration tests in feature branches. I thought of the following workflow (and problems):

- a new feature is developed in multiple different projects (for example UI changes and Backend functionality) in a respective feature branch called "feature1"
- when changes are committed, Jenkins is triggered via web-hook and builds each feature branch respectively
- therefore I need a way to collect all changes across all repositories that have this exact feature branch "feature1" and build it respectively, for all other dependencies the master branch shall be used
- the number of repositories may grow in the near future, so I don't want to hard-code all repository-urls in the pipeline script
- each repository is a maven project, so building a feature branch and installing it into the local jenkins repo will overwrite a potential "master artifact" therefore potentially corrupting dependencies for other repositories

I am struggling to find the most effective and reasonable strategy for managing this project structure. It might be wise to change maven versioning to encorporate branch names into the version tag, but this will further complicate dependency management within all repositories.

If someone knows a clever solution to this problem or can recommend a whole other strategy for tackling this, please let me know.

Comment: _"each repository is a maven project, so building a feature branch and installing it into the local jenkins repo will overwrite a potential "master artifact" therefore potentially corrupting dependencies for other repositories"_

**I do not believe this is accurate. Each branch of the same code base would have a unique artifact version.**

Comment: Are you planning to deploy the UI and back-end artifacts somewhere so that you can run the integration tests? What is your strategy here?

Comment: @OSGIJava thanks for your feedback. but how can I differentiate between two artifacts with the same groupid, artifactid and (snapshot-)version? The whole things gets packaged into a war file that is deployed on a jetty server for integration testing.

Comment: If you trigger more than one build of the same project then it will override the old build. Isn't that what you want? Don't you want the latest code to be built and deployed?

Comment: @OSGIJava not really, I want to deploy the project that has the feature branch changes, so that I can make sure the integration tests run successfully before merging the feature into master

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have multiple projects configured in Jenkins. These projects use the same branch name. You want to be able to add new projects to Jenkins to be built and deployed to your test integration environment but you do not want manually change the branch name in each Jenkins project when the branch changes, when you need to work on a different feature.

The solution is simple. In Jenkins use `Environment variables`:

> These key-value pairs apply for every build on every node. They can be used in Jenkins' configuration (as $key or ${key}) and will be added to the environment for processes launched from the build.

For example you can declare DEV_BRANCH variable to point to your feature branch and then in every project specify `Repository URL` as `${DEV_BRANCH}/projectName`

Comment: This sounds similar to something I came up with, basically checkout out all dependencies that have the feature branch as well, otherwise using the master branch. But for this to work I need a way (some Jenkinsfile pipeline config) to dynamically checkout all repositories in the organization. The project is basically a multibranch project in Jenkins that dynamically adds all repos in my organization. Do you know by chance how such a configuration could work specifically in a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: If I am not incorrect, you want Jenkins to query your company code repository, find all projects with a given branch name, configure Jenkins jobs for them all, including specific deployment scripts, then deploy them all so that integration tests can be executed?